# How to place two divs next to each other -HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been googling this and have found many answers, but none of them work in my situation because one of the divs is a gallery with multiple images. Basically, I'm trying to put an image and another gallery in the center of a page next to eachother.

**HTML snippet:**

```
<div class="sides">
    <div class="featured-item">
        <p class="featured-label">This weeks Featured Item is Mint Chip Cupcakes!</p>   <a href="#"><img src="img/mintchip.jpg"></a>

    </div>
    <div class="sides">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="A Happy Birthday Mario Cake">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="A Pizza Hut Cake">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="A Makeup Cake">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="A Makeup Cake">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/156.jpg" alt="A Makeup Cake">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sides {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 612px;
}
```

I also tried using each div seperately and using `margin-left`, `margin-right` but no luck. The `max-width` is `612px` because that's the `max-width` of the gallery. I tried setting it to `1000` and it shows a ton of the images very widely. 
**Result:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a12u.png
One image is on top of the other, and they are on the left side of the screen.

Comment: You have an issue with your structure. The first `sides` div is a parent element of the second `sides` div. If you want them next to each other you may close the first `sides` div before opening the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are using the "slides" class name for what seem like unrelated divs.  I'd change that; it's only going to cause you grief.  Next, the wrapper should have a set width and be centered with an auto margin -

```
.my-Wrapper-class {
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Now float the two divs holding your picture and slide show -

```
.featured-item {
    float:left;
}

.flex-slider {
    float:right;
}
```

You can add a margin to either of those until it's spaced to your liking.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! Would this worth with 3 divs as well?

Comment: No, that would only work for two divs.  If you want to do more than two, float them all left and control their spacing through their right margin and/or width properties.

Comment: I tried that, and the gallery images are stuck on the bottom left of the screen ignoring the ".sides" div that has a max-width in the middle of the screen. Picture: http://i.imgur.com/pymoCvr.png

Comment: If that div is too wide, it's going to drop down to the next line.  Make sure your child divs don't exceed the width of your wrapper div.